# I can't find the dp formula for counting the number of connected components that contains all value from $1$ to $k$.

Tags: graph-theory, recursion, trees, dynamic-programming

We are given a connected graph with $n$ vertices and $n-1$ edges, and a parameter $k$. Each vertex $i$ has a value $c_i \in \{1, 2, \dots, n\}$; these values may repeat. Count the number of connected subgraphs that contain at least one vertex of each value from $1$ to $k$. Here $n\leq10^4$, $k\leq10$. Give the answer modulo $10^9+7$.

I think this graph is a tree. So we can use dynamic program on tree. And $k\leq10$, so we combine that with bitmask. But I can't find the recurrence formula.

Everybody helps me find the recurrence formula, please!

> Original Problem (*Vietnamese Coastal and Northern Plains Olympiad 2021*) 
> *Vietnamese statement:* https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zbia22jve9EFB9Y8jH-SZG8m3b8nTi9n/view 
> **Problem 2. SHOPPING MALL** 
> A shopping mall has $n$ kiosks numbered $1$ to $n$, the $i$-th kiosk sells items $c_i$. That shopping mall has $n-1$ two-way street numbered from $1$ to $n-1$, the $k$-th street connects kiosk $u_i$ and kiosk $v_i$. 
> The system of paths ensures travel between any two kiosks. 
> During the epidemic period, people want to close some kiosks to easily control buying and selling activities as well as communicating with customers. When a kiosk is shut down, all the roads leading to the kiosk will be blocked for security purposes. In addition, because they do not want to affect customers too much, the supermarket wants to make a plan so that the kiosks are still in operation and must satisfy the following two conditions: 
> The kiosks still in operation must connect with each other: That is, between any two kiosks that are still open, there must be a path (through unblocked roads). 
> All items with numbers $1$ through $k$ (essential items) must be available at at least one operating kiosk. 
> Two plans are said to be different if one kiosk is deactivated in one plan but still in operattion in the other. 
> **Requirements:** How many different plans satisfy the above condition? 
> **Data:** Input from text file KIOSKS.INP 
> Line 1 contains 2 positive integers $n \leq 10^4, k \leq 10$ 
> Line 2 contains $n$ positive integers $c_1, c_2, …, c_n (\forall i: c_i \leq n)$ 
>  − 1 next lines, the $i$-th line contains two positive integers $u_i$ and $v_i$ 
> Numbers on the same line of input are separated by a space 
> Result: Write to the text file KIOSKS.OUT a single integer that is the remainder in division: number the solution that satisfying the problem condition for $1000000007 (10^9 + 7)$ 
> **There are 3 subtasks:** 
> Subtask 1 (30% of the score): $k = 1$ 
> Subtask 2 (30% of the score): Each kiosk has no more than 2 roads connecting to it. 
> Subtask 3 (40% score): No additional constraints other than those stated in the assignment.

Comment: I would like to clarify. For each $i$ there is a component with an edge marked $i$ in our graph?
Maybe we are talking about counting the total number of such graphs. The wording is very unclear.

Comment: I also don't understand the question. You said the graph is connected, so there is only one connected component. So the answer is 1 if there exists an edge with value $i$, and $0$ otherwise?

Comment: @kabenyuk No, there may be not for each i. The answer will be 0

Comment: @Josse van Dobben de Bruyn I am so sorry for my bad English. What do you call a connected component after delete some edges nà vertices of that graph?

Comment: If not for each $i$, then specify what you need to count.
It feels like an interesting question, but not clearly formulated.

Comment: Ah, maybe you need to count the number of connected components of the graph $G_i$ obtained from $G$ by removing all edges whose value is different from $i$?

Comment: I still think I'm missing something... The answer of the question I have in mind should be rather small, so there is absolutely no need to reduce modulo $10^9  + 7$. Furthermore, this looks like a question from an ICPC-style programming contest, where the values of $n$ and $k$ are usually very large to make the problem more challenging. Do you maybe have a link to the original problem?

Comment: I think that rather than "connected component" the question should say "connected subgraph", but I second the request to see the original source.

Comment: @Josse van Dobben de Bruyn , Misha Lavrov         For more details, I have update the original source.

Comment: [Here's](https://oj.vnoi.info/contest/dhbb21_k11) a more official link, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @Misha Lavrov, Yeah, you are right

Comment: OK, now I understand the problem. Did you achieve partial results? Can you solve the smaller subtasks? Can you give a valid algorithm which is too slow? (I think I can give an $\mathcal O(n 2^{2k})$-time algorithm, which is probably too slow for the given bounds and time limit. The limits suggest the existence of an $\mathcal O(n 2^k)$-time algorithm, but I didn't find it yet.)